# Wants all the references at the end of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to add all the references at the end of beamer slide. I have a .bib file but it is showing error with "it is part of preamble" for (`\bibliography{.bib file}`) but when i used it in the preamble it shows no error but no references also

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemeDresden}

\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsbsy, pstricks, pst-node, pst-text, pst-3d}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{scholar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \tiny{\printbibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Large{Thank You.}\\
%\Large{Its party time now!}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Queries:
1. I used the similar code in article (\document)  is shows no error of preamble.
2. Why it is so hard to compile with .bib in beamer but it is very easy with article?

Comment: Have you cited anything?

Comment: NO is that the problem

Comment: @Moody: Yes. Add `\nocite{*}` just before your bibliography (actually, anywhere in your document). Then you also need to compile using `biber` (since you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

Comment: @Werner: thanks, i am using WinEdt how can i compile using biber.

Comment: @Moody Install my plug-in [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php) in WinEdt and you'll have a toolbar button to run Biber.

Comment: @Moody: See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154755/5764).

Comment: @Werner: Can you help me with decreasing the fontsize in bibliography? bcoz \tiny or \small is not working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem seems to be a combination of not citing anything and not running Biber as announced.